# Email Verification using re.search Python

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, python-re

Need help making email verifications with the variable 'pattern' and making it so that it loops if it doesn't contain whatever is within the pattern. Required to use re.search. I tried a couple of things for the last hour and this is where I'm kind of lost.

````
import re
pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]' + '[a-zA-Z0-9]'+'@[a-zA-Z]'+'(.com/.edu/.net)'
user_input = input('Enter Your Email:')
while user_input is not pattern:
    if (re.search(pattern,user_input)):
        print(re.seach(pattern,user_input))
        print('Valid Email:'+ user_input)
    else:
        print(re.search(pattern,user_input))
        print('Invalid Email:'+ user_input)
        user_input = input('Enter Your Email:')```
````

Comment: You should spend some time reading through a regular expression tutorial. The way you've written your pattern, it only matches email that contains two letters/digits, an `@`, a single letter, and then anything matching the pattern `.com/.edu/.net` (where `.` means "any character") . So for example this matches: `aa@a.com/.edu/.net` as does: `aa@axcom/bedu/cnet``

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a good resource for testing out regular expression patterns.

Comment: You may actually be a lot closer to the regex than you think.  The '+' token means one or more of the previous pattern.  So you really want your + signs _inside_ the string.  Also, the variation token (I just made that up) is the pipe character '|' not '/'.

Comment: I should also noted that your while condition `user_input is not pattern` is really very far from what you want.  You want to stop the while loop when the user_input can be matched by the pattern.  In my answer below, I show how to use `break` to end a loop when a condition matches.

Answer (score 1):

The code is great, but the pattern lacks a bit of functionality. In fact for e-mail addresses, it misses the dash `-` and the underscore `_`. Luckily, you can just say to match `\w`. It is the same as if you would have specified `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. (it still misses the dash though, so your approach is good but too short.) Anyway, there are a few further things that an address should meet.

1. it must start with a alphabetic character
2. While theoretically, the address could be composed of a single character at the start and only to after the @ sign, and be almost infinitely long, it is highly unlikely

I suggest the pattern
`'[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{0,42}@[a-zA-Z]{2,42}\.((com)|(edu)|(net))\b?'`

Limiting the number of characters with `'{m,n}'` lets you ensure that you won't have an overflow error when storing the address. Well and addresses shorter than `'a@bc.st'` simply don't exist as at least two characters are required.

Lastly, the or-operator applies only to the immediate adjoin characters, so you need to group the mail extensions:
`((com)|(edu)|(net))`

```py
import re
pattern = '[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{0,42}@[a-zA-Z]{2,42}\.((com)|(edu)|(net))\b?'
while True:
  user_input = input('Enter Your Email:')
  if re.match(pattern, user_input):
      print(re.search(pattern,user_input))
      print('Valid Email:'+ user_input)
      break
  else:
      print(re.match(pattern,user_input))
      print('Invalid Email:'+ user_input)
```

I think, it is better if you use `re.match()` as it matches the string right from the start. Usually one doesn't like if you end up with `1abc@def.comm` to be a valid address (because `re.search()` would find the valid string `abc@def.com`. With the same argumentation, you should add a `\b` to the end of the pattern

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight modification to your pattern and to your code.

```
import re
pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+(\.com|\.edu|\.net)'
while True:
  user_input = input('Enter Your Email:')
  if (re.search(pattern,user_input)):
      print(re.search(pattern,user_input))
      print('Valid Email:'+ user_input)
      break
  else:
      print(re.search(pattern,user_input))
      print('Invalid Email:'+ user_input)
```

Here's an example run:

```
Enter Your Email:fred
None
Invalid Email:fred
Enter Your Email:mark@so.com
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='mark@so.com'>
Valid Email:mark@so.com
```

Comment: ...although note that in practice this isn't a great pattern, because it's not going to match something like `bob@regex101.com` or `alice@big.org.uk`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression for some detailed discussion on the topic of address validation with regular expressions.

Comment: Good point.  I considered finding a good resource to point him to since I recognized that even the corrected pattern was insufficient.  I'm glad you did.  I prioritized on the obvious errors with the pattern .

Comment: Shouldn't it be an escape character before the `.` and grouping before the OR-operator?: `((\.com)|(\.edu)|(\.net))`

Comment: I certainly agree with escaping the `.`, but I haven't found the need to group before the OR-operator.